# How can I get message/reaction logs from Discord as triggers to a swift program?

Tags: swift, discord, keystroke

I'm currently looking to automate counting in Discord in Swift using keystrokes. The bot that registers the counting, however, has a small chance to not validate a number. To get around this, I am trying to use the check reaction, the validation from the bot, as a trigger to type the next number. Is there a way I can fetch the "reaction data" from discord to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code right now that you could show, or anything that you've tried?

Comment: You might want to look into the Discord API - for Swift there is [Sword](https://github.com/Azoy/Sword)

Comment: @Levi_OP I added my current code

Comment: @aheze thanks! would you mind sending some sort of tutorial or way to learn how to use it?

Comment: @NicoRose I've only done a bit, but you can [join the discord](https://discord.gg/discord-api) to get started

Comment: @aheze thanks, any idea where I could get a command list or something? If not that's ok

Comment: @NicoRose yeah the [documentation](https://azoy.github.io/Sword/Enums/Event.html) is pretty thorough. For anything that doesn't work, just pop it in the discord.

Comment: @aheze cool, I've looked farther into it and it seems that the API isn't quite what I'm looking for. However, I did find a GitHub project (https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DiscordChatExporter) that's been working. Anyway, thanks for your help!